# Unable to modify dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, datatable, dataset

Here is a piece of my c# code

```
if (dsResult != null && dsResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dsResult.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        dr["Date"] = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Date"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
}
dsResult.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
```

What i'm trying to do is that the dataset has a `Date` in format d/m/yyyy and i'm trying to modify the data to format `yyyy-MM-dd` but my dataset is not getting updated.

Comment: How are you viewing the data after the update to determine if it worked or not?

Comment: my putting a break point in the visual studio

Comment: Were you trying to modify the database? `AcceptChanges` doesn't do that.

Comment: @JohnSaunders u mean modify the datatable

Comment: I mean modify the data in a database.

Comment: no no......i am not trying to modify the database.I have a Date field in datatable with a particualar format, i'm trying to update that date format to another date format in datatable

Comment: What database server are you using?

Comment: @jade If the data type of the column is Date then why are you calling Convert.ToDateTime and then setting it to a string?

Comment: @DanielKelley When i look into MySql the Date is in format "2013-01-07" but when filled in the Datatable the format changes to 1/7/2013 00:00:00 AM.....to be precise to change format

Comment: I think you need to add the row to the datatable.

Answer (score 2):

The way the **date** is *stored* and the way it's *displayed* are two very different things. The reason it shows as `1/7/2013 00:00:00 AM` in the `DataTable` for example is because it's showing the default display for the `DateTime` based on your culture settings.

However, this is often not how you want it displayed, so there are a number of ways to skin this cat, but I'll give you a couple. First and foremost, you could simply change the culture of your application so that it's displayed the way you want by default.

```
CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
```

Now, when you display `DateTime` values you're going to get that culture by default when you issue for example:

```
var dt = new DateTime();
dt.ToShortDateString(); // here is where the culture is used
```

You may also find that you have a specific spot in your application where you need to display it a certain way, well you can do that to:

```
var dt = new DateTime();
dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); // custom formatting on the fly
```

So, in short, you **don't need to** change it in the `DataTable`. Regardless of how it's *displayed* the ***value*** is the same.

Comment: well i'm not actually displaying it but converting this datatable into a csv file using a common function and i want the date field to be in yyyy-MM-dd format

Comment: @jade, creating a CSV file is no different than displaying it. The underlying ***value*** of the `DateTime` has literally *no* bearing on how it's displayed or even output to a CSV file. A CSV file is a comma-delimited text file yes? Then that means you're going to have to ***display*** the `DateTime` in a `string` format yes? Well then that means when you're putting the `DateTime` into the CSV file either format it the way you want it on the fly (like the second example) or change your culture.